# Connected and Disconnected sets

Tags: real-analysis

> If $A$ and $B$ are connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^p$, give examples
>   to show that $A\cup B$, $A\cap B$, $A\setminus B$ can be either
>   connected or disconnected.

The solution for the problem is:

Let $A=[0,2]$ and $B=[1,3]$. Then $A\cup B = [0,3]$, $A\cap B=[2,3]$, and $A\setminus B=[0,1)$ are all **connected**. On the other hand, let $A=[0,1]$ and $B=[2,3]$. Then $A\cup B = [0,1]\cup [2,3]$ is **disconnected**. If $A=[0,3]$ and $B=[1,2]$, then $A\setminus B=[0,1)\cup (2,3]$ is **disconnected**.

I do not understand why this is the case?

Comment: Do you see that in the disconnected cases, the union and set-minus sets are the union of disjoint sets? Do you understand the connected examples, or are you struggling with, basically, what it means to be connected?

Comment: @amWhy I cant see why (no pun intended) and I am struggling with the example given both connected and disconnected.

Comment: Shouldn't $A \cap B=[1,2]$?

Comment: I just "got it": the "pun"...very funny!

Comment: @MITjanitor I am not sure, but I copied it straight down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for fixing $A\cap B=[1,2]$ as MITjanitor points out in the comments, the disconnected examples are correct, except I've noticed you have not given an example for $A\cap B$.

First, lets answer the question of *why* the sets you gave are disconnected. By definition, all we need to do is find two disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ where $A\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq V$. For this, take $U=(-1/2,3/2)$ and $V=(3/2,7/2)$. Can you check these contain $A$ and $B$, respectively?

For the case $A\cap B$, let $$A=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:\, x^2+y^2=1,\ y\geq0\right\}$$ (the top half of the unit circle), and let $$B=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:\,x^2+y^2=1,\ y\leq0\right\}.$$Their intersection gives $$A\cap B=\{(-1,0)\}\cup\{(1,0)\},$$and these points can be separated by open balls centered at each point with radius $1/2$.

Comment: I am still struggling to understand. For the solution to my problem, where it says "Let $A=[0,2]$ and $B=[1,3]$. Then $A\cup B = [0,3]$, $A\cap B=[2,3]$, and $A\setminus B=[0,1)$ are all **connected**." Why is that? I dont see how it is connected.

Comment: @Q.matin Because they are intervals. Again, $[0,2]\cap[1,3]=[1,2]$, not $[2,3]$. Try drawing it on a number line and see if that helps.

Comment: Ahh, no wonder! Drawing it on a number line did help, a lot!